# Excel: Using MAXIFS with OR function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm am hoping to use an OR function in a MAXIFS function as one of the criteria, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
=MAXIFS(P:P,O:O,OR("<67",362))
```

Basically, I just want to find the max of a value in one range, if the value in an adjacent range is either less than 67 or equal to 362. I know the problem is with how I am trying to use the OR function, because if I just use "<67" then it works, but I want to 362 to be part of that range as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Max L's reply, though a touch more succinct:

`=MAX(MAXIFS(P:P,O:O,{"<67",100}))`

Comment: Sir this is what I was trying last night. but it was not working for me. So I commented using `AGGREGATE()` and later deleted also. Sir one question without using the `OR()` the curly braces checks as `OR()` here?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Using an array for the *criteria* parameter generates an array whose entries are the result of the `MAXIFS` for each of the entries within the criteria array. If you enter `MAXIFS(P:P,O:O,{"<67",100})` into a worksheet cell somewhere, you will obtain two results within a horizontal range.

Comment: Alright Sir understood now =)

Comment: Perfect, I was trying to figure out how array generators worked in Excel. This did the trick, and you are a credit to your house, my guy.

Answer (score 1):

You could run 2 MAXIFS and find the max between them:

```
=MAX(MAXIFS(P:P, O:O, "<67"), MAXIFS(P:P, O:O, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:

```
=MAX(IF((O:O<67),P:P),IF((O:O=361),P:P))
```

This formula uses the IF function twice, one for each criteria specified.

The first IF function filters the values from range P:P where the corresponding values in range O:O are less than 67, and the second IF function filters the values from range P:P where the corresponding values in range O:O are equal to 361.

The MAX function then only considers the filtered values and returns the maximum value that meets the criteria.

Comment: It's better to use the `MAXIFS` function, which employs implicit detection of the last-used cells within the ranges passed, and so, even when passed entire column references (`O:O`, `P:P`, etc.), disregards cells beyond the last-used cells in its calculation. Using `MAX` and `IF`, however, does not have that advantage, and so your formula will be forced to calculate over all 1,048,576 cells, even if there is data in only the first 100 rows or so.